# jQuery how to multiple duplicate elements?

Tags: jquery, duplicates, date-arithmetic

I have this line of jquery

```
$('#qty input').on('input', function() {
                var price = $(this).prev('#price input').val();
                var qty = $(this).val();
                $('#amount').html(parseFloat(price * qty).toFixed(2));
                $('#linetotal input').val(parseFloat(price * qty).toFixed(2));
            });
```

and its HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><select name='itemone[]'>
        <?php echo $items; ?>
    </select></td>
    <td><input name='itemtwo[]' type="text" class="irow"></td>
    <td id="price"><input name='itemthree[]' type="number" step="any" class="irow" value="0.00"></td>
    <td id="qty"><input name='itemfour[]' type="number" step="any" class="irow" value="1"></td>
    <td id="linetotal" class="text-right"><p id="amount">0.00</p>
        <input name='itemfive[]' type="hidden" class="irow" value="0" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

what it does it to calculate the value of the third td and fourth td and the result will be displayed on the last td. It went successful. However, when I click a button, which will copy the exact tr as new table data, then the same "id's" is being used. now, the calculation of that row is not working.

Is their a way, that I can make this calculate, using the same ID's even if I got 2 or more same ID?

I have tried the `sibling()`, `next()`, `prev()` and I failed to avail.

How you can help me.

TIA,
Nimitz

EDITED:

Here's the successful image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6f93ZQiD1h_V0dvbThocVdlekU/edit?usp=drivesdk

if two or more tr (unsuccessful): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6f93ZQiD1h_MmxzYUVLT3JzQWs/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to change from using ids to classes to target your elements.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2ouvxbb/1/) is a working version, The html looks a little messy but it is a repeated copy of yours with added class attributes.

Each row will calculate the total independently.

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name='itemone[]'>
            <?php echo $items; ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='itemtwo[]' type="text" class="irow" />
    </td>
    <td id="price" class="price">price
        <input name='itemthree[]' type="number" step="any" class="irow" value="0.00" />
    </td>
    <td id="qty" class="qty">
        <input name='itemfour[]' type="number" step="any" class="irow" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td id="linetotal" class="linetotal text-right">
        <p id="amount" class="amount">0.00</p>
        <input name='itemfive[]' type="hidden" class="irow" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name='itemone[]'>
            <?php echo $items; ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name='itemtwo[]' type="text" class="irow" />
    </td>
    <td id="price" class="price">price
        <input name='itemthree[]' type="number" step="any" class="irow" value="0.00" />
    </td>
    <td id="qty" class="qty">
        <input name='itemfour[]' type="number" step="any" class="irow" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td id="linetotal" class="linetotal text-right">
        <p id="amount" class="amount">0.00</p>
        <input name='itemfive[]' type="hidden" class="irow" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
$(".qty :input").change(function () {
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price :input').val();
    var qty = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.amount').html(parseFloat(price * qty).toFixed(2));
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.linetotal input').val(parseFloat(price * qty).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: Hello @angusf, than you for the code. It works well, but I wanted to change it while on edit. I tried to change it to `$(".qty :input").on` but it doesn't work. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @NimitzEBatiocoJr. The .change() event does this. If you are just typing a number into the text box, make sure you tab or click somewhere else to trigger the event, or make sure your .price input has a value other than 0.0 in it.

Comment: Yes it change, but it would be nicer if while changing the number on the textbox, it will change the output value.  Well, thanks for your code though.

Comment: @NimitzE. you may want to bind the key up event also http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ in that case

Comment: @augusf it seems it only works on html that was loaded first, since the second TR was only created using jquery. I mean, I have a button, that adds another tr to have a multiple lines, I guess that is the reason that it is not working on my page. but on your fiddle, it works...

Comment: yes @augusf, now, both your jquery and my previous jquery works well, if the two TR are already present on the loading of the whole page.. I believe, when I added the new TR on my table, as I click my  add TR button, then the multiplication process was not performed since, the TR is just an imaginary on my page. How can I make this work :(

Comment: When you add the new TR to the page, you will have to attach the event handler to the new element. Effectively run that javascript code again. You may want to extract the inside code into a stand alone function to avoid repeating code when binding events to the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

I not 100% sure what you are trying to do.  But I think these will help:

http://api.jquery.com/first/
http://api.jquery.com/last/

The jquery selects should return a list of things so first or last could give you the one you want.

Comment: imagine or picture out, that I have 10 same TR... Then I will calculate each rows.

which is price * quantity = total price

I was successful achieving that, however, when two or more same TD is present, the second TD will stop calculating (second row)